# Print all li's children's text without getting sub children's for each li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

Hi I am trying to print all li's elements text without getting their sub children's text but I am not able to get proper result:

My HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>child demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
    </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="topnav" id="abc">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
    <li class="topnav1">Nested item 1</li>
    <li class="topnav1">Nested item 2</li>
    <li class="topnav1">Nested item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

<script>
 var li = $("#abc > li");
 var arr = [];
 for(var i=0;i<li.length;i++){
   arr.push($(li[i]).clone().children().remove().end().text());
 }
 console.log(arr);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

After the script is run I am getting weird things in arr:

The output comes like:

```
0:"Item 1"
1:"Item 2↵    ↵  "
2:"Item 3"
```

Can anybody explain me meaning of these arrows and how can I just only get the text of all li's.
I want my array to be:

```
0:"Item 1"
1:"Item 2"
2:"Item 3"
```

Where I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text covers the whole node, and it probably is reading the line-breaks in the child `li` also.

You could just use `trim()` to remove that like

```
var li = $("#abc > li");
 var arr = [];
 for(var i=0;i<li.length;i++){
   arr.push($(li[i]).clone().children().remove().end().text().trim());
 }
 console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you. It's right I am just curious as this method takes lot of time. Is there a fast and a more efficient solution to do this?

Comment: I have also found one more solution: $( "ul.topnav > li" ).each(function( index ) {
  arr.push( $( this ).html().split("\n")[0]);
}); Is this one fast or the real one?

Comment: You haven't used `$(this)` ? I just noticed that right now!

Comment: The one you put just assumes that the line break will always be in the end ;)
trim will remove it from both sides.

Comment: That is okay but is there any more fast way to do this?

Comment: Don't think so, at least I am not aware of any, you could use vanillaJS method for textNodes but I am not sure it will make a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this is faster but is certainly more cleaner

```
var arr = [];
$('.topnav > li').filter(function() {
    var temp = $(this)[0].firstChild.data;
    arr.push(temp);
});
```

Comment: yes this is more cleaner but I just want to add in the solution here also while giving the data it gives you the nodes. So the correct will be arr.push(temp.trim()).